# SwiftyJSON file 100+ errors

Tags: ios, xcode, swifty-json

I am having trouble working with SwiftyJSON. I put the SwiftyJSON file in my Xcode project, and added the SwiftyJSON pod to my xcworkspace. I opened my xcworksapce to find that the SwiftyJSON File has many errors. What's going on? I am using Xcode 7 and swift 2.2. Is there a certain version of SwiftyJSON that I need to have for Xcode 7?

Comment: SwiftyJSON [requires](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) Xcode8, so what you need is Xcode8 rather than Xcode7.

Comment: So SwiftyJSON requires Xcode 8 but not Swift 3? @holex

Comment: There is a [Swift 2 branch](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/tree/swift2)

Comment: I just tried that, and there are still a lot of errors @vadian

Comment: forget about what I just said, I forgot to get the SwiftyJSON File from the github page. I was using the one for the Xcode 8 (the one I already had). Thanks :).  @vadian